Why doesn't the $ operator accept a variable or an evaluated argument as its second argument when used in prefix notation?
A column in a data.frame can be accessed using $, like so:
iris$Sepal.Length

#   [1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4 4.6 5.0 4.4 4.9 5.4 4.8 4.8 4.3 5.8 5.7 5.4 5.1
#  [19] 5.7 5.1 5.4 5.1 4.6 5.1 4.8 5.0 5.0 5.2 5.2 4.7 4.8 5.4 5.2 5.5 4.9 5.0

The data.frame column can also be accessed with $ using backtick syntax:
`$`(iris, "Sepal.Length")

#   [1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4 4.6 5.0 4.4 4.9 5.4 4.8 4.8 4.3 5.8 5.7 5.4 5.1
#  [19] 5.7 5.1 5.4 5.1 4.6 5.1 4.8 5.0 5.0 5.2 5.2 4.7 4.8 5.4 5.2 5.5 4.9 5.0

However, if a variable or function is provided as the second argument, the results are different. For example, when the second argument is provided via a variable:
var = "Sepal.Length"
`$`(iris, var)
# NULL

or via a function:
`$`(iris, ifelse(TRUE, "Sepal.Length", NA))
# Error in `$`(iris, ifelse(TRUE, "Sepal.Length", NA)) : 
#  invalid subscript type 'language'

Why does $ seemingly behave differently when its second argument is provided by a variable or a function, as opposed to a string?

Try getElement(iris, var) instead.

I don't know why the R developers chose to do this with $, but for general context about the use of barewords (unquoted variables which are not evaluated) see Why do programming languages use delimiters (quotes) for strings? on PLD. Hadley Wickham's example of the cement() function in the Quasi-Quotation chapter of Advanced R is also relevant.

@MrFlick, apologies, I didn't realise i had the power to reopen it automatically (i thought it would go to vote). My rationale for (voting to) reopen, is because the linked question askes how to achieve something (it's what I was trying to do when I came across the phenomenon discussed in the above question), but it doesn't go into great detail about why that happens. Please take my 'reopen' as a suggestion.

If you look at the help page of $ (help("$")), you will find the following:

How $ is used

x$name

This tells how $ is used. Of course you can also use its functional form ($(x, name))

What name stands for

A literal character string or a name (possibly backtick quoted). For extraction, this is normally (see under ‘Environments’) partially matched to the names of the object.

So only a literal string and name object are allowed.

[[ vs $

Both [[ and $ select a single element of the list. The main difference is that $ does not allow computed indices, whereas [[ does. x$name is equivalent to x[["name", exact = FALSE]]. Also, the partial matching behavior of [[ can be controlled using the exact argument.

This emphasizes the fact that the index cannot be computed when using $, in addition to saying that partial matching is allowed.



It's also in the R Language Definition: $ allows only a literal character string or a symbol as the index. That is, the index is not computable . I suspect it's been there from the earliest versions of R but the earliest specification I can find is version 2.15.12 (2012). Would be interested if anyone has the version 1 R Language Definition.

This issue is well described by the existing R-FAQ question Dynamically select data frame columns using $ and a character value. The problem is you're using the wrong subsetting operator here. If you want to use expressions use [[. For example
iris[[ifelse(TRUE, "Sepal.Length", NA)]]

R was designed with interactive use in mind and a lot of the decisions about how operators work are influenced by that. R uses non-standard evaluation in many places to reduce avoid extra quoting or redundant references to variables.
The $ operator itself is implemented as the do_subset3 function internally. Internally it adjusts the parameters passed to the function via the fixSubset3Args function which automatically turns any parameters into strings without evaluating them. You can read the source for that function to see that it checks for strings and symbols explicitly and that's where the error you are seeing about "invalid subscript type" is being thrown.
This is exactly the behavior defined in the ?Extract help page. The function is listed with x$name where "name" is defined as

A literal character string or a name (possibly backtick quoted). For extraction, this is normally (see under ‘Environments’) partially matched to the names of the object.

There's no differences between quote(`$`(a, b)) and quote(a$b). Those are exactly the same call to R.
So yes, it behaves "differently" because that's exactly how it's designed to behave.

@BChristianKamgang explained the documentation for the different behaviour. I'll try to add some implementation details.
Clearly $ is using non-standard evaluation.  For example, in the expressions
iris$Sepal.Length
`$`(iris, Sepal.Length)

which produce the same result, it can't evaluate the 2nd argument which looks like a variable named Sepal.Length, because normally there is no such variable.  It has to look at the argument and interpret it as the name of a column in the dataframe.  It accepts names and constant character strings and rejects any other kind of expression.
In your example where you created var <- "Sepal.Length", it follows the same logic when evaluating
iris$var
`$`(iris, var)

It looks at the expression for the second argument, and sees var.  It converts that to a string without evaluating it, and then looks up the column named "var", and doesn't find one.
In your ifelse() example, the 2nd argument isn't a name or a character value, so it is immediately rejected.
